# Как извлечь текст до и после таблицы (текст который относится к таблице, небольшие заметки к таблице) с помощью табула?

Tags: python, excel, csv, jupyter-notebook

Как извлечь текст до и после таблицы (текст который относится к таблице, небольшие заметки к таблице) с помощью табула? В итоге в .csv должны быть экспортированы таблицы с небольшим текстом, до и после нее.

Ссылка на пдф файл: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zrp6KUE3nu9jLuIxuuTqSpI3PLiVDxOQ/view?usp=sharing

В таблицах есть текст небольшого размера (заметки к таблицам), расположены до и после таблицы

Нужно извлечь таблицу и текст до и после таблицы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Картинки какие-то что ли приведите или текст. Что извлечь, откуда извлечь?

Comment: текст и таблицы извлечь из пдф